# Remove the Discontinuity

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

Would it just be x+2? I worked on it a few times and its not 1, or 0

[image: Problem]

Comment: Could you show your work for this question? If you factorise $x^2-x-6$ properly the answer is neither $0$ or $1$.

Comment: You can “remove the discontinuity” because the discontinuity at $x=3$ is a “removable discontinuity.” Yes, that’s what it’s really called. So what makes a “removable discontinuity”?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $5$

This can be obtained in two different ways.

The first and most obvious is to check the values for $x$ very close to $3$

Put $x=2.999$ and $3.001$ and see (assuming you have a calculator)

Otherwise try using some factorization:

$(x+2)(x-3)/(x-3)=x+2$ so $f(x)=x+2$

Put $x=3$ to get $f(x)=5$